# Colorware with Apple Products

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod, warranty

Could someone who has, or knows someone who has, used [Colorware](http://www.colorware.com/) for an Apple product comment on their experiece?  I'm thinking about getting an third-generation iPad colored through Colorware, as they seem to be a solid coloring solution.  Are the devices returned in factory condition?  Does Apple accept colored devices if, say, a pixel died in the first month or so?  Does the coloring look professional?

Comment: "Our color customization typically voids the original manufacturer's warranty" ([Source](http://www.colorware.com/support.aspx)). I'd be surprised if Apple was any different.

Answer (score 1):

Colorware [clearly](http://www.colorware.com/c-3-computers.aspx) states that their customization voids Apple's warranty:

> ColorWare Inc. replaces all existing Apple Inc. warranty policies and procedures with a ColorWare Inc. warranty, the documentation for which is included with all products purchased from ColorWare Inc.

More detailed information is available at ColorWare's [warranty page](http://www.colorware.com/Static_Data/warranty.htm), where they specify that they cover "workmanship defects and non-accidental hardware failures". While this sounds similar to Apple's [warranty](http://images.apple.com/legal/warranty/docs/NA_iPad_Warranty_v20.pdf), it would be difficult to expect similar quality of service, especially outside of the United States.

Comment: Thanks, but you've only answered a small part of the question.  I'm looking for the opinion of someone who's actually used Colorware (=  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

I know the above question was posted some time ago,  but perhaps others have thought about ordering a customized Apple product from Colorware.

I purchased my Macbook Pro in 2010 in the Apple Retail Store located in Greensboro, NC.

2 weeks later,  I shipped my Macbook Pro to ColorwarePC.   My color choice was Ferrari Red,  with trackpad and hinge in Smoke White.

Some 2 weeks later,  I had my one of a kind Macbook back in hand.

First..... I have visited them for training and technical questions regarding software and technical questions about upgrading RAM,  etc.  (Since this was my first Mac).   NEVER ONCE did anyone at Apple EVER even try to avoid helping me.  In fact, they all gathered around wanting to check it out. That was in 2010.  Here it is 2016, and they STILL flock to help me,  and everyone wants to know where they can get one.   Of course,  the cost keeps most only observers.

I still have the same Macbook... It still looms lime it did the day it came back from Colorware PC.   Only one light surface buff mark.   I can't say enough about the incredible glossy finish.

I have replaced the 350GB HDD with a 1TB SS Drive.... and I have replaced the standard 4GB RAM with 16GB RAM.   Yes... You read that correctly.   Nothing special needed... and yes,  FULLY compatible,  with no glitch and no rejection.   Lightning speed.

BTW... It will void your Apple warranty,  but I've never met the very first Macbook user who ever had to utilize the warranty anyway.   Screens are the biggest risk,  and are not covered anyway.

Hope this helps.

John

Answer (score 0):

I would be happy to provide current photos of the Ferrari Red MacBook Pro.   Even years later,  I think you will be impressed with the quality of finish.

John

Comment: Go for it! Definitely still curious (=